# Spring RedisTemplate retuning valid Zrange but Is Not Returning any key

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I am using Spring RedisTemplate to connect to Redis.  I am using zadd to add data then calling zrange to check data value.  It returns data just fine but when I call Key * i am not getting any results.  Really Confused!!  Please Help!!  But when I run jedis it is working fine I see entries from cli etc.

```
System.out.println("**********  ZRANGE IS " + redisTemplate.zrange(patternEmailsSetKey, 0l, -1l));
    final Set<String> keys = redisTemplate.hkeys("*");
    System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& KEY SIZE IS " + keys.size());
    for(String key: keys) {
        System.out.println("key: "+ key);
    }
```

Returned

**********  ZRANGE IS [{"subject":"ab ","eest":"aa","urls":["aa","ss"],"dd":0,"Id":11,"bId":999}]
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& KEY SIZE IS 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ZRANGE` and `ZADD` are commands for `Sorted Set`, while `HKEYS` is command for `HASH`. So you are adding elements to a `Sorted Set`, while trying to get fields of a `HASH`.

If you want to get all members of the `Sorted Set`, you need to use the `ZSCAN` command.

Comment: The point is you can use zrange key start end to get by position in rediss itself but not sure how can get a range in springBoot!